# why two session ids JSESSIONID and session-id used in a grails application?

Tags: session, grails

I was doing some analysis on a grails application and i noticed two cookies being sent by browser to server everytime. If i understand correctly one session id should be enough to implement sessions in a web application but i am wondering why are two session ids being used instead of one. The cookie looks as follows:

```
JSESSIONID=4206209230A211D7D45DF1124B2E08C1; session-id=37663030303130312D353235342D313339652D383235372D363464386133343030303032
```

I apprecaite any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSESSIONID is generated from the servlet-container like **jetty** or **tomcat** or the builtin if you run a grails app standalone.

The session-id is generated from the used http-server like **apache**, etc.

I assume, you run the grails application behind an apache/http-server proxy?

If you access the servlet-container directly, only the JSESSIONID cookie is send.